# What are the Djinn from Clash of the Titans (2010) based on?

Tags: mythology, clash-of-the-titans-2010

I was watching *Clash of the Titans* (2010) and I really liked the Djinn, I thought the idea of bark skinned desert sorcerers was really cool and wanted to read more about it. I know Djinn is usually another name for Genies or spirits from Arabic myth but that isn't anything like what we see in the movie, I thought that perhaps they were based on something else but just took the name from the Djinn but I can't find anything.

Are they actually based on anything from Mythology or just fabricated for the film?

Comment: From a set interview; **Q. Is Sheik Solomon based on anything from mythology or was this a new creation for the movie?**

**Letterier:** *It’s based on wood. (laughter) No, no, I mean, it’s a Djinn, Arabic spirits. I mean they’re like nomads.  You’ll  see what purpose he serves in the movie.  This movie is about opening your eyes, just, you know, widening your world, not being afraid, not being trapped in a box.  It’s all about this, so he serves a purpose in this matter.  Yeah.* - So, it appears to have been mostly an invention of the filmmakers; https://tinyurl.com/y4kr6cvy

Comment: @Valorum why havent you written it as an answer?

Comment: @Shreedhar - if you read it carefully, it didn't really answer the question asked

Comment: @Valorum  I read your last sentence as a part of the response in the interview ‍♂️ my bad.

Comment: The first time the Djinn speaks, it is in Arabic, I recognized a few words.